# How do I get images randomly from the realtime database in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageview

What I want is to get the image of a product randomly whose product Category is "top" into the imageView.
On the other page, image was retrieved using Picasso. What should I do?

ImageView's id is "randomImageTopIv".[image]

If you need additional information, please let me know.

```
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference randomsRef = db.child("Users").child(uid).child("Products");

    randomsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                int rand = new Random().nextInt(count);
                for(int i = 0; i< rand; i++){
                    String productTitle = datas.child("productTitle").getValue().toString();
                    testRandomText.setText(productTitle);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As you asking [how to get a random child from the Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+get+random+child)?

Comment: Yes, but it's hard to understand with the writing that already exists...

Comment: It's also hard to help better than was done in those questions without seeing what you've already tried based on the answers that were given there.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I practiced with the existing answer, but it didn't work out.
First, we experimented with whether random data can be loaded into TextView rather than images.
However, it has become a code that only brings information about the most recently added clothes.
Is my approach wrong?

Comment: "didn't work out" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to import productTitle of all products randomly, but currently, the code only imports productTitle of the last added product. That is my problem.